# Align an anchor vertically and horizontally within an absolute positioned div

Tags: html, css

I am stuck on something I have been trying to achieve for the past hour and a half. I have two divs on top of one another, where the top one contains an anchor that I want to center in the div. How can I achieve this?

HTML:

```
<div class="browser-home">
    <div class="browser-bar">
        <img src="img/browser-bar.png" alt=""/>
    </div>
    <div class="browser-canvas">
       <img src="img/a2o.png" alt=""/>
       <div class="browser-hover">
           <a class="folio-link" href="#">view case study</a>
       </div>
   </div>
```

CSS:

```
div.browser-home {position: relative;}

div.browser-home img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

div.browser-canvas {
    background: #f6f6f6;
    border: 2px solid #d6d6d6;
    max-width:1250px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

div.browser-canvas img {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 5.6em;
}

div.browser-hover {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 900;
    background: rgba(0,0,0, 0.7);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.34s ease-in-out;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}

div.browser-canvas:hover div.browser-hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [absolute centering](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/08/09/absolute-horizontal-vertical-centering-css/) trick as follows

```
.folio-link {
  display:inline-block;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  margin:auto;
  height:0px; /* imp */
  text-align:center;
}
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Hu7Xs/1/)

Comment: This works, but.

Since my button has some styles applied to it it got stretched out to the left and the right. How can I avoid this from happening?

Comment: @user3466235 i didn't get it, which styles in the shared code are you referring to..?

Comment: I didnt list the styles, but as I see, the only thing I`ve added is the transform: scale(1.1); , which requires the anchor itself to be inline-block. But this doesnt seem to be the problem... hmm.

Comment: So, I have put the anchor inside a <span> , and applied you snippet to it. The button looks good now, but it went to the far right of the div. What now?

Comment: Fixed this again. The anchor was floated right, and I disabled the float right property, but I replaced it with your snippet in a hurry. Had some margins too.. 

Thank you!